# Dynamic php responsive navigation bar

Tags: php, html, css, navbar, responsive

I made a navigation bar that grabs links in the database and populates them in a button element. On hover the button display the links stored in db.

At php and mysql level everything is working well.

My problem is in the HAMBURGUER icon.

When i resize my browser window less than 600px my hamburguer button does not open with the links inside it. It does nothing, and the links stay there side by side with the hambuguer icon.

I tried to solve the problem without any luck. I think the problem lies in CSS and in the order i placed my html class inside the PHP code.

**PHP**

```
require_once('../backend/dbconst.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu";
$result = $con->query($sql);
echo '<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">';
    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<div class="dropdown">';
        echo '<button class="dropbtn">'.$row['menu'].'<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>';
            echo '<div class="dropdown-content">';
                $sql1 = "SELECT sublink FROM menu_sublink WHERE id_pai=".$row['id'];
                $result1 = $con->query($sql1);
                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
                    echo '<a href="'.$row1['sublink'].'">'.$row1['sublink'].'</a>';
                }
            echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
echo '</div>';
```

**JAVASCRIPT to trigger the hamburguer button**

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

**CSS menu style and media queries for hamburguer work properly**

```
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropbtn {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

**A window screen capture**

[image]

Comment: have you checked if you are able to click the button. Try some console.log and see if you are able to click the button.

Comment: Yes. I can click the button. JAVASCRIPT Console shows no error.

Comment: The problem has to be due to the two stage algorithm i have created. First it query a table for the name of the menu. Then it fetch in another table (links table) the links from that menu matching the id of the menu with a id_father column in the links table.
It works well, and populate the navbar well. But cannot implement the hamburguer to open both menu entries and it's sublinks,

Comment: Actually I dont have data so just looking into code I am giving my best guess. If you can provide some dummy content then it will help in finding the issue.